# php img email tracker not working even if the img is displayed in clients

Tags: php, email

I tryed to track if an html email is opened by inserting an image like this:

```
<img height="210px" width="210px" src="http://example.com/emailimg1/c00015.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;">
```

and I presume that if the image is displayed then it has to be downloaded from my webserver. So I addedd this line to .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^emailimg(.?)/(.*)$ emailTracker.php/$1
```

and emailTracker.php is the following:

```
<?php 
require_once'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

include "../phpComp/trackEmail.php";

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$imgId = substr($pieces[1], -1);
$clientHash = substr($pieces[2],0, -4);
$imgFormat=substr($pieces[2], -4);

trackEmail($clientHash);

$filepath="img/email".$imgId.$imgFormat;

if (file_exists($filepath))
 {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    readfile($filepath);
 }
```

and trackEmail.php is the following:

```
<?php

function trackEmail($clientHash)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
    $dateDay = date('d-m-Y', time());

    try
    {
        include_once '../absolute/myConnection.php';
        $dbSvr = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($connParams);
    }
    catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e)
    {
        //*******debug**********->
        $response=$e->getMessage();
        //echo $response;
        //*******debug**********<-
    }
    catch (Zend_Exception $e)
    {
        //*******debug**********->
        $response=$e->getMessage();
        //echo $response;
        //*******debug**********<-
    }
        $data = array(
                'clientHash'=>$clientHash,
                'date'=>$date
        );
        $insertResult = $dbSvr->insert('emailAccess', $data);
    }
    catch (Zend_Exception $e)
    {
        //*******debug**********->
        $response=$e->getMessage();
        //echo $response;
        //*******debug**********<-
    }
}
```

so:

- if I access from browser my address http://example.com/emailimg1/c00015.jpg then my mySql table correctly records an access;
- if instead I send the mail and then I open it from eudora desktop, outlook.com from browser, outlook app from Android then no access is recorded from mySql.

My questions are:

- am I doing something wrong?
- could it be that the mail server (Zoho) download the img and embeds it in the html mail, so no client is then downloading it?

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all email clients strip out images precisely because they are used to track users. That's why this doesn't work.

Comment: That would be understandable. But actually what's happening here is that the img is displayed by the client but my server doesn't record any access to the file.